# What sets default values for Mac env vars other than .bash_profile?

Tags: bash, mac

I amusing a Mac. My company used to host a proxy server at http://proxyA and I had my `http_proxy` & `https_proxy` vars set to that value in my .bash_profile.

Recently we changed to a new proxy (let's call it http://proxyB) and I've changed the appropriate env vars in .bash_profile. However, when I open up a new terminal those env vars are still set to  http://proxyA.

It must be set to the wrong value somewhere in the OS but I can't fathom where. Can anyone suggest where the incorrect value might be getting set?

Answer (score 0):

Found them. they were in `/etc/profile`. I removed them from there and its all good again.